# What's the underlying difference of normally start tomcat and debug start tomcat?

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, jvm

I want to know what does eclipse do for JVM or other things if i start tomcat in debug mode?

I also want to know why I can make my changed code efficient immediately If i start tomcat in debug mode?Who make it become a reality?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have breakpoints and variable watch in debug mode, but at the cost of speed.

Comment: Whether some jvm arguments will be passed into jvm if debug tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In debug mode you can set breakpoints, so the JVM will pause there and using that, if you are in the debug perspective, you can then see all the variables, this is useful if you are getting an error or you don't know why a certain variable is null, for example.